# preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'Array', to be a valid callback

Tags: php

this code return an error
preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'Array', to be a valid callback

```
    $tPattern = array(
        "/\\\(\d{1,3})/",
        "/\\\\\(/",
        "/\\\\\)/"
    );

    $tCallback = array(
        function($m) { return chr(octdec($m[1])); },
        function($m) { return '('; },
        function($m) { return ')'; }
    );

    return preg_replace_callback($tPattern, $tCallback, $s);
```

I have replace it by

```
        $s = preg_replace_callback("/\\\(\d{1,3})/", function($m) { return chr(octdec($m[1])); }, $s);
        $s = preg_replace_callback("/\\\\\(/", function($m) { return '('; }, $s);
        $s = preg_replace_callback("/\\\\\)/", function($m) { return ')'; }, $s);
        return $s;
```

but I'd like to know how could I do to use an array instead of 3 call to preg_replace_callback ?

thank's

Comment: I'd suggest researching on delegates and closures inside PHP. Since every method in PHP is a generic method (You do not declare your Data Types), this should be achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly `preg_replace_callback` does not let you provide the callbacks as an array (like `str_replace(array, array, $s)` ie), so you have to iterate over the callbacks and do the function call there

```
$result = $s;
foreach ($tCallback as $key=>$callback) {
    $result = preg_replace_callback($tPattern[$key], $tCallback[$key], $result);
}
return $result;
```

If you're running PHP7, you can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) [as Misyaath Mohammed suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36088014/1557526) in combination with [`array_combine()`](https://php.net/array_combine)

```
$patterns_and_callbacks = array_combine($tPattern, $tCallback);
return preg_replace_callback_array($patterns_and_callbacks, $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one

```
<?php
$subject = 'Aaaaaa Bbb';

preg_replace_callback_array(
    [
        '~[a]+~i' => function ($match) {
            echo strlen($match[0]), ' matches for "a" found', PHP_EOL;
        },
        '~[b]+~i' => function ($match) {
            echo strlen($match[0]), ' matches for "b" found', PHP_EOL;
        }
    ],
    $subject
);
?>
```

If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise subject will be returned unchanged.